# What are the differences between "The Strain" TV series and the books?

Tags: adaptation-comparison, the-strain

I have been watching the "The Strain" on television.

Is there somewhere I can go to find out about the major differences between the TV series and the books (or is there a list someone can post from an authoritative source)?

Comment: I've edited so it stops being an open-ended "list" question. Feel free to revert if you don't like what I've done.

Comment: thx Richard , this is much better

Comment: I can't find any rundown of the changes so far, aside from [del Toro previously saying that there would be "major detours" from the books](http://www.thewrap.com/guillermo-del-toros-the-strain-will-take-major-detours-from-the-books/).